# Table only with foreign key in entity framework 6 (Fluent Api)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, fluent-interface

How to map foreign keys from two different table to one table in fluent Api?
My two model is like

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Userid { get; set; }

    public string PassWord { get; set; }

    public bool premium { get; set; }
}


public class Roles
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And 3rd table which has primary key of above table as foreign key?

```
public class CustomerRoles
{
   public string RoleName { get; set; }
   public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

How to map in Fluent Api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string Userid { get; set; }
    public string PassWord { get; set; }
    public bool premium { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerRole> CustomerRoles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CustomerRole> CustomerRoles { get; set; }
}
public class CustomerRole
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasMany(c => c.CustomerRoles).WithRequired(cr => cr.Customer);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(r => r.CustomerRoles).WithRequired(cr => cr.Role);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerRole>().HasKey(cr => new { cr.RoleName, cr.UserId });
    }
}
```

PS: Class name should not be plural, it can confuse with array property.

## update how to use it

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var ctx = new AppContext())
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer { Userid = "A" };
        ctx.Customers.Add(customer);

        Role role1 = new Role { Name = "Role1" };
        ctx.Roles.Add(role1);
        Role role2 = new Role { Name = "Role2" };
        ctx.Roles.Add(role2);

        customer.CustomerRoles = new[]
        {
            new CustomerRole { Customer = customer, Role = role1 },
            new CustomerRole { Customer = customer, Role = role2 },
        };

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: A customer can have only one user id hence there should be one to one relationship with customer and CustomerRole.

Comment: what do you mean? a customer can have multiple roles and a role can be owned by multiple customers, is that what you meant by one to one?

Comment: Thanks. I will try to correct and get back. And yes, a customer can have multiple role and 1 role could be applied to different customers.

Comment: Hi @Yuliam Chandra. I am very late to reply on this. But where is table of Customer Roles in AppContext class? Should we declare to create a table for CustomerRoles?

Comment: If a table has foreign key relationship, it will be discovered by EF, the CustomerRoles table will be be created on the database, but if you want to add `public DbSet<CustomerRole> CustomerRoles {get;set;}` property, thats'okay..

Comment: OK. I have explicitly DbSet<CustomerRole>. So while saving information i need to save in Customer table first then in CustomerRole table. Right? Because as per your example there is only one SaveChanges()

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan, you don't have to call separate `SaveChanges`, if you have a FK reference or know the id (which the id is not identity), you could just assign it and save them all together...

Comment: Thanks Yuliam Chandra.